# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.unwrapInvocationTargetException

Tags: java, apache, exception

The code is not written by me, so I am not able to give proper input for question ;), but still want to know the cause of the exception in general. :)
I have installed OpenCRX CRM, and when I run, the following exception is thrown,

> SEVERE: Begin event threw error
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.unwrapInvocationTargetException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/Throwable;
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:184)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:83)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:592)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.(Connector.java:66)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1282)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:507)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1323)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2750)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:828)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:757)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:133)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1211)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:551)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.unwrapInvocationTargetException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/Throwable;
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:184)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:83)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:592)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.(Connector.java:66)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1282)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:507)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1323)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2750)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:828)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:757)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:133)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1211)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:551)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:615)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

I would like to know when such a exception is thrown? What are the possible solutions should I try ?
Thank you :)

Comment: It looks like an error due to malformed/bad configuration (xml file). It's difficult to say more than that considering the provided input.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError often caused by using wrong version of library. Check your dependencies

Answer (score 3):

This may be because of library conflict. May be there will be an old library or conflicted (conflict with app libraries) library in tomcat lib folder. Try to force to use app libs

Answer (score 0):

I can give only a hint. In my case I had changed the name from a propertie inside my maven properties. I got the same error and same behavior. The tomcat was able to start but the application was not able to boot up with spring boot. After renaming the tag to the old name the application was able to boot with spring boot and tomcat aswell.